# Windows HPC server and Azure

Tags: azure, hpc

I read that one can use Windows HPC server with Azure. It says one can run the HPC server on head node on premises and use the compute nodes on the cloud.

My question is Can I create a head node on Azure and use the compute nodes on Azure.
It will be great helpful if there is some tutorials on how to do that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no. The implementation as it stands today is to use Azure as a means of extending your existing WinHPC cluster. So, if you have a head node and n nodes on premise, but need more (for non MPI methods) you can (using HPC Server 2008 R2 Sp1) extend your cluster into the cloud. The HPC control panel will create N+2 instances in azure based on your request (the "+2" is for two WCF proxies).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is now possible in SP3